# Speed up copy-paste in PyGTK?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, clipboard, pygtk

In a helper script for [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey) (see below), I would like to accomplish the following:

- store the current clipboard content in a variable
- put some new content on the clipboard
- "paste" that new content, using Ctrl+V
- put the original clipboard content back onto the clipboard

Implementing the steps above *literally* in PyGTK always resulted in the **old** content being pasted. After some messing around, I noticed that, counterintuitively, the actual paste was carried out *after* the old content had been written back to the clipboard.

After *a lot* of messing around, I came up with the following workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

import time
import threading

class Clipboard:

    def __init__(self):
        self.clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)

    def get_clipboard(self):
        Gdk.threads_enter()        
        contents = self.clipboard.wait_for_text()
        if contents is None:
            contents = ""        
        Gdk.threads_leave()        
        return contents

    def fill_clipboard(self, content):        
        Gdk.threads_enter()
        self.clipboard.clear()
        self.clipboard.set_text(contents, -1)
        self.clipboard.wait_is_text_available()
        Gdk.threads_leave()


def paste_content(keyboard,
                  content):

    clipboard = Clipboard()

    # Save current clipboard content as a variable
    new_content = content
    old_content = clipboard.get_clipboard()


    # Put new content onto clipboard
    clipboard.fill_clipboard(new_content)

    # Paste it  
    keyboard.press_key("<ctrl>")
    keyboard.press_key("v")
    time.sleep(0.05)
    keyboard.release_key("<ctrl>")
    keyboard.release_key("v")

    # Restore the clipboard content to its pre-call value
    # TODO: can't we just wait for a "paste event" somehow?
    def restore_clipboard():
        time.sleep(0.88)
        clipboard.fill_clipboard(old_content)
    clipboard.fill_clipboard(old_content)

    restore_thread = threading.Thread(target=restore_clipboard)
    restore_thread.start()
```

*Note that the `keyboard` object below is a small wrapper object around PyGtk's keyboard functions, made available to user scripts by Autokey. Eventually I intend to write my own tiny class for it instead of passing it as an argument (like with the `clipboard`), but I just want to see if the principle works.*

This works...sometimes, sort of. When I'm typing quickly and hitting a shortcut key that fires this script with some predefined content (say, the unicode character "∮"), I can type at least 5 more characters before the ∮ finally appears. Also, more often than I like, the *old* clipboard content is actually pasted, instead of ∮. And, this behavior also seems to depend on the application I'm pasting into...

Am I misunderstanding something here? Why do I need all the mutexes,  delays, awkward constructs...? More importantly, what's the better way to do this?